# Como pasar el resultado de un metodo arrayList a un Map en java

Tags: java

Hola amigos buenas tardes,

Como es la manera mas efectiva de lo que regresa un ArrayList y almacenar su resultado dentro de un mapa?

```
public static ArrayList creaListaArchivos (ArrayList<String> archivosOrigen) {
    String nombreOrigenArchivo ="";
    String sinN0_N1 ="";
    String nombreSiguiente="";
    ArchivoUtilCombinado archivoUtilCombinado = new ArchivoUtilCombinado();
    ArrayList<ArchivoUtilCombinado> archivosCombinado2 = new ArrayList<ArchivoUtilCombinado>(); //JJ
    for (int i = 0; i < archivosOrigen.size(); i++) {
        nombreOrigenArchivo=archivosOrigen.get(i);
        sinN0_N1=nombreOrigenArchivo.replaceAll(".n0", "").replaceAll(".n1", "");
        archivoUtilCombinado.nombreFinal= sinN0_N1;
        archivoUtilCombinado.archivosOrigen.add(nombreOrigenArchivo);
        nombreSiguiente=archivosOrigen.get(i+1);
        
        
        if(nombreSiguiente.contains(sinN0_N1)) {
            archivoUtilCombinado.archivosOrigen.add(nombreSiguiente);
            
            archivosCombinado2.add(archivoUtilCombinado);
            //
            i +=1;
            
            // i = i +1;
            archivoUtilCombinado = new ArchivoUtilCombinado();
                        
        }else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    return archivosCombinado2;      
}
```

Lo que sucede es que quiero que como resultado del metodo anterior se lo pase al siguiente metodo:

```
public static Map<String, String> obtenerListaArchivos(String rutaBase, String patron) {
    Map<String, String> lstArchivos = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<String> archivosOrigen = new ArrayList<String>(); //JJ
    File dir = new File(rutaBase);
    String[] ficheros = dir.list();
    if (ficheros != null) {
        for (int x = 0; x < ficheros.length; x++) {
            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(patron);
            Matcher mat = pat.matcher(ficheros[x]);
            if (mat.matches()) {
                lstArchivos.put(ficheros[x], rutaBase + ficheros[x]);
                archivosOrigen.add(ficheros[x]);//JJ
                
                LOG.info(ficheros[x]);
            }
        }
               ArchivoUtilCombinado.creaListaArchivos(archivosOrigen);
                    
        }
    return lstArchivos;
}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar con este problema por favor, intenté realizar un casteo pero no tuve exito, si hay algo que no se entienda con gusto lo aclararé, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Cratus, el método **creaListaArchivos** está dentro de la clase **ArchivoUtilCombinado**?, si no es así, cambia en  la linea **ArchivoUtilCombinado.creaListaArchivos(archivosOrigen);** el nombre de la clase, osea **ArchivoUtilCombinado** lo cambías por la clase que contiene el método. si está en la misma clase que **obtenerListaArchivos()** simplemente quitas el nombre de la clase.